# add country data each time I create a user in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I use a library to get City and Country from a IP.

So, what I do is when a user register, I add those data to request, to insert it in DB.

```
$location = GeoIP::getLocation(Config::get('constants.CLIENT_IP')); //     Simulating IP in Mexico DF
    if (!is_null($location)){
        $country = Countries::where("name", $location['country'])->first();
        if (is_null($country)){
            $country_id = Config::get('constants.COUNTRY_ID_DEFAULT');
        }else{
            $country_id = $country->id;
        }
        $request->request->add(['country_id' => $country_id ]);
        $request->request->add(['city' => $location['city'] ]);
        $request->request->add(['latitude' => $location['lat'] ]);
        $request->request->add(['longitude' => $location['lon'] ]);
    }else{
        $request->request->add(['country_id' => Config::get('constants.COUNTRY_ID_DEFAULT') ]);
        $request->request->add(['city' => "Paris" ]);
        $request->request->add(['latitude' => "48.858222" ]);
        $request->request->add(['longitude' => "2.2945" ]);
    }
```

Thing is I must run this in different places (AuthRequest, UserRequest, etc)
I must say that AuthRequest and UserRequest differs on their validation, the process is not the same.

Admin can add user with UserRequests, but AuthRequest is register process.

What should be the best way to always add those data when user

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the Eloquent events to automatically run code when certain events are fired. In your case you can use the `created` method.

This way you will define only once your process.

The docs about [Eloquent model can be found here](https://laravel.com/docs/master/eloquent#events).

If you have a lot of processes like this, I'd advise you to create Model Observers classes where you can define your automated processes.